# HBase Put statment for rows is not splitting the load with other region servers

Tags: hbase

I have 9 node hbase cluster with 8 region servers. I have pre-split my HBase table as below.

create 'table1', 'cf1', SPLITS=> ['1', '3', '5','7','9','b','d']

I have done bulk put, in which case the load spread across all the region servers based on the key.

However, when i tried Put, using java HBase client API, i could see the requests are going through master alone.

Is there a way to ensure, even Put statements spared across the region servers evently.?

Answer (score -1):

The splits mentioned during create table is to create multiple regions for that table based on the key range. So once you create the table with above mentioned splits, you will be having 8 regions created for that table, and location of these 8 regions within Region Server will be done by HBase. To see the regions created for this table and the location of the region in regionserver we can use the web gui of Hmaster.  [I've created the table and the information of regions & key range can be found in this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylp2K.png)

Comment: The question is about load balancing. I did all those things and my bulk load  had load balanced very well. I was just wonder about the Put requests alone. You can check the question again.